# Bing Translator API with Coldfusion

Tags: azure, coldfusion, railo, bing-api, lucee

In my coldfusion application im using Microsoft Bing Translation API.
To be honest I don't know where to start? let me write what I have already done.

- Registered (https://datamarket.azure.com/account)
- Got 3 things from Microsoft

  - Primary Account Key Eg(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
  - Customer ID         Eg(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
  - App ID              Eg(mynameid)

What I have already tried OR Failed Attempts :

ColdFusion:

```
<cfhttp url="http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?appId=mynameid&from=en&to=de&text=HELLO"  result="rs" method="post"></cfhttp>
```

OUTPUT:
['to' must be a valid language Parameter name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXD49.png)

```
 <cfhttp url="http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate"  result="rs" method="post">
   <cfhttpparam name="appId"    type="header" value="mynameid" />
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="method" value="POST" />
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="from" value="en" />
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="to" value="de" />
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="text" value="HELLO" />
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#rs#">
```

Comment: Just checking, but posting those keys publicly is not a good idea at all. In case those are real, I'd go cancel them immediately.

Comment: @Lanny Bose  Thank you very much for you kind suggestion... that's  why I kept dummy key.

Comment: I replaced your keys Amir.

Comment: @Mark A Kruger Thank you! sorry about that I just wanted to write my problem very detailed and clear

Comment: So noe thing to note is that your "Values" are not going to be passed in the code above. If you have a variabled called "mynameID" containing a value (i.e. 1234) you would need `name="appID" value="#mynameid#"`  It's the pound signs that render the value of the variable.

Comment: here im passing direct appid it is in testing that's why im not keeping any variables

Comment: the error seems to claim that "de" is an invalid target language. Is it case sensitive? Should it be De instead of de - or maybe DE?

Comment: just tried (DE&De) `<html><body><h1>Argument Exception</h1><p>Method: Translate()</p><p>Parameter: to</p><p>Message: 'to' must be a valid language Parameter name: to</p><code></code><p>message id=3722.V2_Rest.Translate.4CCFB5E0</p></body></html>`

Comment: Does it really require the values to be passed as type="header"? I would have expected "to" to be either a URL parameter type="URL" or type="formField" depending on whether the API requires POST or GET.

Comment: Yes, looking at [the example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512387.aspx), language is passed as a URL parameter, not a header.

Comment: `<cfhttpparam type="formField" name="method" value="POST" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="from" value="en" />
       <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="to" value="de" />
      <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="text" value="HELLO" />` Result Same

Comment: try changing type="formfield" to type="URL" ... Leigh says the docs indicate a URL param is needed.

Comment: **Now error changed** `<html><body><h1>Argument Exception</h1><p>Method: Translate()</p><p>Parameter: appId</p><p>Message: Invalid appId Parameter name: appId</p><code></code><p>message id=3722.V2_Rest.Translate.4CD8BE0A</p></body></html>`

Comment: Where do you see appID in the docs? Skimming the http docs, it looks like an [authorization token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx) is used.

Comment: Amir - you have a bit of work to do here. Your must FIRST make a request using your secret and appID to obtain an authorization token. THEN you use the token to make your tranlsation request. Spend a little more time understanding the examples in the API documention. It doesn't look too hard - you will get there!

Comment: @MarkAKruger & Leigh great help im reading examples when its done diffidently i'll post here for the community for others.